# Why do my val_loss fluctuate and have enormous values while val_categorical_accuracy are more or less constant throughout all epochs?

Tags: python, validation, computer-vision, loss-function, conv-neural-network

I adapted the AlexNet architecture, preprocessed the images, augmented the images, used LeakyReLU activation function, utilized dropouts, and had tried adjusting a learning rate. However, these trials aren't improving my model's val_loss and val_categorical_accuracy. What should i do? Embedded are my model's fitting and history visualized =

[my model.compile()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhdhG.png)

[my model's fitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCcXN.png)

[Training and validation loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrfGS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might occurs due to **several** reasons, the most common reasons,

---

- The number of examples of the validation set are not big enough
- A validation step at each epoch might be small
- Validation set has examples not in the training set
- Training set batch size not quite good compared with validation set size
- Model biased against (**high bias**) some classes at **training** set and those
  classes **more likely** to be in the **validation** set.
- ... etc

---

You could check **n - randomly chosen mislabeled examples** from the **validation** set, usually is the best thing to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i'm going to try tweak my model according to them and see if one of the suggestions work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i tweaked my model too much. I tried using purely AlexNet with ReLU function and it did the job, albeit too slow (175 s/epoch). I also didn't know that to have a layer (both Conv and FC layers) use an activation function, we must specify the function within the layer's parameter (before, i had used the .add after said layer and turns out it didn't register as the activation function of said layer therefore the layer didn't learn anything throughout the fitting process). I really need to learn more about building CNNs i guess.